# Javascript Reduce for object

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

```js
const obj = [
  {
    name: "john",
    marks: 50,
  },
  {
    name: "mary",
    marks: 55,
  },
  {
    name: "peter",
    marks: 75,
  },
];
```

I want to calculate sum of marks using reduce method.

I tried through this way -

```js
const sum = obj.reduce((next, number) => {
  console.log("next", next.marks);
  console.log("number", number.marks);
  return next.marks + number.marks;
});

console.log(sum);
```

But I am getting sum as `NaN` and overall result as -

```
next 50
number 55
next undefined
number 75
NaN
```

I am not sure why next is getting `undefined` in between.

How can I calculate sum through `reduce` method ?

Comment: `.reduce()` is a method of `Array.prototype` and not available on objects. If you can call `.reduce()` without an error you don't call it on an object... The variable with the misleading name `obj` is an array of objects but not an object. Hence the title is not correct.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `reactjs` and `jquery`? Both tags are not relevant for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a default value to `reduce` as 0

```js
const obj=[{ name: "john", marks: 50 }, { name: "mary", marks: 55 }, { name: "peter", marks: 75 } ];


const sum = obj.reduce((acc, number) => {
  return acc+ number.marks;
}, 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Please explain the *"I am not sure why next is getting undefined in between."*

Comment: because in OP next is a number, not an object. so can't access the property in the next

Comment: Why didn't you close this as a dupe (which it obviously is)?

Comment: @Andreas because of efforts which Sachila put into answering this post. Let as many downvotes come.